# What is the order of constructor call in virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

What is the order of constructor call in virtual inheritance in c++?

For the following two cases of multiple inheritance;

(I) for the following code, without virtual inheritance;

```
class a
{
    public: 

        a()
        {
            cout<<"\t a";
        }

};

class b: public a
{
    public:
        b()
        {
            cout<<"\t b";
        }

};

class c: public b
{
    public:

        c()
        {
            cout<<"\t c";
        }

};

class d: public c
{
    public:

        d()
        {
            cout<<"\t d";
        }
};

class e: public c, public d
{
    public:

        e()
        {
            cout<<"\t e";
        }
};

class f: public b, public e
{
    public:

        f()
        {
            cout<<"\t f";
        }
};


int main()
{

    f aaa;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
     a       b       a       b       c       a       b       c       d       e       f
```

(II)With virtual inheritance of class e:

```
class a
{
    public: 

        a()
        {
            cout<<"\t a";
        }

};

class b: public a
{
    public:
        b()
        {
            cout<<"\t b";
        }

};

class c: public b
{
    public:

        c()
        {
            cout<<"\t c";
        }

};

class d: public c
{
    public:

        d()
        {
            cout<<"\t d";
        }
};

class e: public c, public d
{
    public:

        e()
        {
            cout<<"\t e";
        }
};

class f: public b, public virtual e
{
    public:

        f()
        {
            cout<<"\t f";
        }
};


int main()
{

    f aaa;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
     a       b       c       a       b       c       d       e       a       b       f
```

Can someone explain how the output is obtained in both cases?
How does virtual inheritance affect the construction of objects?

Answer (score 3):

The virtual base class will be initialized firstly, otherwise, the direct base classes will be initialized in left-to-right order of the base class declaration.

For class `f`, `class f: public b, public e`, there's no virtual base class, the direct base class `b` will be initialized at first, then `e`. (left-to-right order)

For `class f: public b, public virtual e`, the virtual base class `e` will be initialized at first, then `b`.

See [Initialization order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order):

> 1) If the constructor is for the most-derived class, virtual base
>   classes are initialized in the order in which they appear in
>   depth-first left-to-right traversal of the base class declarations
>   (left-to-right refers to the appearance in base-specifier lists)
>
> 2) Then, direct base classes are initialized in left-to-right order as
>   they appear in this class's base-specifier list
>
> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of
>   declaration in the class definition.
>
> 4) Finally, the body of the constructor is executed